# python file.seek() with os.SEEK_CUR vs os.SEEK_SET

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, file-io

Is there any difference between these two?

A:

```
# seek back by difference from current position
fp.seek(last_read_byte - fp.tell(), os.SEEK_CUR)
```

B:

```
# seek by absolute position from start of the file
fp.seek(last_read_byte)
```

(`fp` is a python file object)

I just thought that **B)** might start reading the file from the beginning. How do I check if that's the case?
Should I worry about stupid things like this?

Comment: As a general rule: is your code too slow? Have you narrowed the slowness down to a bottleneck in this area? If yes, worry about optimizing it. If not, don't worry about anything beyond blatant algorithmic differences (reading a large file N times instead of once; doing a 2^N search when you could do N^2, etc.).

Comment: Yes, it's slow. Now I did not narrowed down, but I thought it could be "blatant" difference if I start reading a huge file from the beginning every time if I encounter a bad line.

Comment: Yep, so this was a reasonable question. It just didn't turn out to be the issue. To find out where it's slow, either run the profiler, or pull our pieces of code and time them with timeit.

Comment: @walkman!  your question about SHORT CODE was AN EXCELLENT QUESTION.  Sometimes questions are deleted here because of moderator silliness.  I will paste in my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling seek will not reread the whole file from the beginning.

And I would use the absolute seek--it's simpler to get right, and to read; it doesn't waste an extra possible syscall for a tell; it doesn't have the race condition if the file changes between the calls...

If you're worried about performance, it's not just more useful, but also easier, to test performance than to try to guess how it works and then try to guess what the performance impact would be. Just create a big file, and try both versions within a timeit.